# Unity sharing Boolean between object scripts

Tags: c#, variables, scripting, unity-game-engine, sharing

I was trying to create a puzzle where a box when moved onto a pressure plate opens a gate. When I get the box onto the pressure plate I was trying to pass a Boolean to the gate telling it to open. Is this the correct way of achieving my goals?

I have unity version 3.4 it is not pro and i'm coding in C#.

Any help appreciated as I have just started trying to learn unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your gate game object has the name *MagicGate* in your hierarchy view and has a script component assigned of type *GateController* containing the following code:

```
public class GateController : MonoBehaviour {
    // Awake(), Update(), ...
    public void OpenGate ();

    public void OpenGate () {
      // code for opening the gate
    }
```

There is another class maybe *GameStatusController* where you detect that the box is at the magic pressure plate (Colliders are useful for this). There you do:

```
GameObject player = GameObject.Find ("MagicGate");
GateController gateController = player.GetComponent<GateController> ();
gateController.OpenGate ();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Would GameStatusController be assigned to anything in the hierarchy or can scripts run without being assigned to anything?

Comment: Not necessarily, it depends on what you want to do: If you need full access to game objects hierarchy and have to rely onn the right timing, you should assign them. All others I keep outside. Often it's OK to have a non-MonoBehaviour class and let it be called by others under Unity control.